# dotnet test - NU1101 (Unable to find <Package>)

Tags: c#, testing, nuget, nuget-package, mstest

I've been putting off learning how unit tests work and how to write them, and I decided to build a stock simulator, where I use unit tests. I wrote a couple simple unit tests, to check Sell and Buy methods, and `dotnet build` is throwing a NU1101 error, saying that the MSTests framework is nonexistent!

I already have the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting` namespace added to the project and the test scripts, I even tried running the `dotnet add package` command with the MSTest information, and it still didn't work.

(In case I'm REALLY Stupid, here are my tests:

```cs
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using StockMarket.FrontEnd;
using StockMarket.BuyerType;
using StockMarket.StockType;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;


[TestClass]
class TestFrontEnd {

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestBuyStock() {

        List<Stock> expected = new List<Stock>() {new Stock("Apple", "AAPL")};
        StockGame game = new StockGame("test");
        game.BuyStock("AAPL");
        List<Stock> actual = game.player.getOwnedStocks();
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);

    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestSellStock() {

        List<Stock> expected = new List<Stock>() {new Stock("Apple", "AAPL")};
        StockGame game = new StockGame("test");
        game.BuyStock("AAPL");
        expected.Remove(new Stock("Apple", "AAPL"));
        game.SellStock("AAPL");
        List<Stock> actual = game.player.getOwnedStocks();
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);

    }

}
```

The full error is:

> error NU1101: Unable to find package MSTests.TestFramework. No packages exist with this id in source(
> s): C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages, nuget.org

If anyone could help me figure out why I'm getting this error, that would be really helpful!

Thanks, The_Game12

Comment: Looks like you have a typo. When I open up the package manager in Visual Studio, the name is "MSTest.TestFramework" not MSTests <- not plural.

Answer (score 0):

@B.O.B. has answered my question, It was a typo, I needed `MSTest` not `MSTests`. Thanks for the help!